# Exporting drupal site from local host causes missing tables

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, database-migration

I have a functional site on my local laptop that I am trying to port to a webhost. Now I was successful in doing this once which must have been a stroke of luck. When an issue forced me to wipe and rebuild, I now find myself unable to migrate the site. Now when I try I get a bunch of errors regarding missing tables.

My process was as follows:
Export mysql table;
FTP website files and sql datatable;
Import sql datatable into new sql database;
Visit the new IP address.

Was I lucky and any way I can fix it? I do not have that much content but I would like to avoid recreating it all.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful I can be without knowing what the specific error messages are.

One thing I can think of is dropping the database and recreating it. Assuming you have command-line access:

```
mysqladmin drop database_name
mysqladmin create database_name
```

And then use mysql to import the new dump file. I find this is the safest way as sometimes mysql complains about "duplicate tables" or something similar when you try to restore over the top of an existing database. I can't give any better advice without knowing what the specific errors are.

I suppose you have already done this, but also make sure you server meets the minimum Drupal requirements: https://drupal.org/requirements